# function field analogy and global/absolute geometry

Tags: nt.number-theory, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry

The "function field analogy" seems to be a topic that is considerably bigger than any one existing writeup conveys. There are several old question on MO and and MathSE that ask for details. One of the most prominent replies has been given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1376/381) and consists simply of a pointer to what is maybe the one single place that sets out to produce a table listing some key statements, namely Poonen's lecture notes ([pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/curves.pdf), see section 2.6).

While such a table is much needed (as witnessed conclusively by 35 upvotes, and counting) it seems to me that there'd eventually be much more to put in it in order to do any justice to the topic. Notably the table ought to have a third column besides arithmetic geometry over number fields and function fields,  namely the column for complex curves/Riemann surfaces, which brings the geometric Langlands correspondence into the picture. And it would be good for such a table to be hyperlinked, since there'd be so much to say on each single one of its entries.

In short, that motivated me to start to try to compile a

- [function field analogy -- table](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+field+analogy#Overview)

on the $n$Lab. I got somewhere, but there is still some way to go. I have some questions, too. (And I would like to stress that nothing in this table is meant as claim of mine, all is me trying to reproduce what is known. If there is anything that seems outrageous, then this is a mistake on my part and I will do my best to fix it.)

So in general one question is: does this look about right? And: what seem to be glaring omissions. (I am aware of some, but I hope to hear of those that I am not aware of yet.)

But I also have this slightly more concrete question:

From one point of view the search for $\mathbb{F}_1$ is the search for a systematic theory that would promote the function field analogy from an analogy to a well controled base change away from $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_1)$. That idea is expressed for instance [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/38097/381) in another previous MO discussion of this point. However, when I scan the literature on $\mathbb{F}_1$ then I see plenty of discussion of zeta functions over these various bases, but little about the bulk rest of the function field analogy table. Does existing $\mathbb{F}_1$-theory have much to say here? For instance the very first line of the (either!) function field analogy table states that $\mathbb{Z}$ is analogous to $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ and to some extent so "as $q \to 1$". So from the point of view of the function field analogy it would seem that the central request on any theory of $\mathbb{F}_1$ would be to give rise to a truth that reads in symbols like "$\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{F}_1[x]$", whatever it is that makes this true. I see that some people do expect just this from a theory of $\mathbb{F}_1$ (for instance in the first footnote [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~waffle/pids.pdf)). However, what I have seen as actual proposals for $\mathbb{F}_1[x]$ seems to be headed in a rather different direction. Unless I am missing something, of course, and my  question is: am I? Which approach to $\mathbb{F}_1$ should I look at for function field analogy purposes beyond (and that probably means: prior to) zeta functions?

Finally to close an already long and vague question with something even broader, just for those who might enjoy it (all others please stop reading): what I am eventually after is an answer to my old MO question *[p-Adic String Theory and the String-orientation of Topological Modular Forms (tmf)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162803/381)*. Namely there are so many hints already in string theory that a function field analogy base-changing us from complex curves to arithmetic geometry over $\mathbb{F}_1$ plays a role, that I'd like to have a good enough mathematical theory of the analogy that would allow to put these hints together to a nice statement. For instance looking at application or mirror symmetry to geometric Langlands as in [Gerasimov-Lebedev-Oblezin 09](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/geometric+Langlands+correspondence#GerasimovLebedevOblezin09) makes one want to ask: "What is a sigma model in $\mathbb{F}_1$-geometry?" I am wondering how far $\mathbb{F}_1$-theory -- or maybe [global analytic geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/global+analytic+geometry)? -- may have gotten in this respect, or what the prospect seems to be. Is this even in the line of sight of present research into $\mathbb{F}_1$? If not: what is, if anything?

Comment: This is not in the direction of your question, but I think there are some difficulties with the analogy when considering arithmetic groups. The patterns in classification of finite subgroups in $GL_n\mathbb{Z}$ and $GL_n\mathbb{F}_p[T]$ seem to differ in a way that is not clear to me. Also, $S$-arithmetic groups in the number field case are $FP_\infty$, but they only have bounded finiteness properties in the function field case.

Comment: Not Weil zeta function?

Comment: @Matthias, thanks for the comment. To my mind, part of the output of a good theory of absolute geometry should be to tell which analogies we should expect to see in the first place. To me the fact, for instance,  that number fields have a genus which behaves in theorems just as the genus of a curve does is enough to conclude that there myst be global theory. Whether this will make combinatorics of finite subgroups be analogous I find secondary, for that seems much less conceptually compelling than, say, the arithmetic genus of a number field.

Comment: @WillSawin You mean Artin zeta function but, yes, it's a glaring omission.

Comment: @WillSawin, right, thanks, fixed now!

Comment: @Urs: I agree that finite subgroups in arithmetic groups may not be the cornerstone or key test case of the analogy, I brought this up because I like it;-) However, looking for analogies is weaker than requiring actual mathematical statements in the line of $\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{F}_1[X]$. For example, although there is a class field theory on both sides, the proper analogy of cyclotomic fields on the function field side is quite a lot harder to find. If $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{F}_1[X]$ would have a deeper meaning, one would expect to be able to transport the proofs ...

Comment: ...from number fields to function fields, and vice versa. The same would hold for Langlands philosophy, the function field case probably would imply the number field case if it was possible to use $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{F}_1[X]$. Summing up, I am not aware of work based on $\mathbb{F}_1$ that would bring the class field theory parts of your table closer together, and relate them not just by analogy. But I am definitely not an expert on this, not even reasonably well-educated...

Comment: @Matthias, thanks for these comments. I do appreciate the cautionary note, it will be good to keep this in mind. I just think that dismissing the analogy as not good enough is not an option, since the many deep aspects that do work out already conclusively show that the analogy is there and is awaiting theory explaining it.

Comment: Regarding class field theory: Borger's absolute geometry "over F1" does involve class field theory, at least his articles do appeal to it at various points. Borger's approach looks promising. Though here too it seems the function field analogy is yet to be attacked.

Comment: @Urs: I did not mean to dismiss the analogy. It's a very good and inspiring thing to have. It would be even better if it was possible to make strict mathematical sense of $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{F}_1[X]$, so that number fields and function fields can be handled with the same arguments. But we seem to be pretty far from that yet...

Comment: Urs, the lambda-algebraic geometry picture that I advocate does work equally well over function fields over finite fields, where it is closely related to Drinfeld modules and shtukas and so on. This is discussed briefly in the last section of my paper "lambda-rings and the field with one element".

Comment: Also, Urs Hartl has a somewhat recent paper "A Dictionary between Fontaine-Theory and its Analogue in Equal Characteristic" with a table of analogies that you might like.

Comment: Which Hartl claims is a sequel to the one by Goss in 'The Arithmetic of Function Fields' edited by David Goss, David R. Hayes, Michael Rosen, pp. 475-482 (http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pFMc1Q0u5HIC)

Comment: @JBorger, re Hartl's article: thanks!, that's excellent. For the moment I have at least included the citation here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+field+analogy#Hartl06

Comment: @JBorger, re function fields in Lambda-geometry: thanks, yes, I did read your article (will read it again in more detail) and saw the comments on function fields. I find the approach fascinating. But could you maybe help me with seeing how the approach not only accomodates the theory over function fields, but possibly explains the analogy? I am hoping that a working theory of absolute geometry should formulate a theory of curves over $\mathbb{F}_1$ which dually reproduces algebraic number theory, and in such a way that base changing to $\mathbb{F}_q$ yields function field theory, etc.

Comment: @JBorger, finally something that won't fit the tiny comment boxes here if done justice, but just to give it a go: I am fascinated by the fact that in your absolute geometry the direct image to the base is forming arithmetic jets. This is, if I understand well, geometrically analogous to how algebraic stacks sit over "formal moduli problems" and the whole reason why I am after the function field analogy here is that I noticed that some aspects of adelic theory as in geometric Langlands follow formally from a suitable direct image to the base of this kind. Except that I need the inverse image to

Comment: ...inverse image to be fully faithful. I see you discuss that in your context it is at least faithful, if I remember well now. I should be able to figure this out myself, but while I have your attention, if I do, allow me to ask: do you see a chance that the essential geometric morphism to the absolute F1-base in your approch may sensibly be factored or otherwise massaged to yield one with fully faithful inverse image? And a related question: is there a chance to have things set up in a way such that the further left adjoint to the inverse image preserves finite products?

Comment: These are sweeping questions, and I'm afraid any answers I have will be much narrower. But here are a few points. First I would caution against hoping for too much from the F1 picture. For instance, any hope that one could base-change a number field over F1 and get a function field is very naive, I believe. For example, the analogue of the Euler characteristic for number fields is the logarithm of the discriminant. So it's hard to imagine a straightforward base-change picture holding.

Comment: Regarding "factoring or otherwise massaging...", in the function-field case, you can massage the inverse image into a fully faithful functor, but I fear it's probably not what you're after. See cor 7.6 in my paper.  Regarding, v_! preserving finite products, this would be like Witt vector functors W preserving tensor products. I think this almost never happens. W does preserve push-outs if one of the maps is etale. It could very well be true that the perfectified W (=inverse limit of W under all Frobenius maps) preserves many more colimits, but I never got to the bottom of that.

Comment: Yet another paper with analogy tables you might like is Deninger's "Analogies between analysis on foliated spaces and arithmetic geometry". You'll see there, however, that the number field picture, the geometric analogues needed are much more sophisticated than the 1940s-era analogies of Weil's Rosetta Stone.

Comment: I just found the paper: M. Blickle, H. Esnault, K. Rülling: Characteristic $0$ and $p$ analogies, and some motivic cohomology. This might contain some more analogies in a more motivic direction...

Comment: @MatthiasWendt, thanks! I only just returned from an off-line week. Have added the reference to the nLab entry, will work in more details later when I have time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest thing missing from this table is the geometric picture over function fields. Almost everything under "complex Riemann surface" on your table makes sense over for algebraic curves over an arbitrary field.

But of course if you go so far as to split the function field case into two columns, the first and second column of your table would be almost identical, as would the third and fourth column, which would be wasteful.

However this does represent how the function field analogy actually works. Usually passing from number fields to function fields is a simple bookkeeping step (changing notation for the same concepts), and moving geometry on curves from one field to another is again bookkeeping, but passing from arithmetic to geometry over a single field requires some insight, although usually a simple one.

Second, I think many mathematicians working in number theory are skeptical of $\mathbb F_1$-theory and prefer to keep it an analogy. One reason is that the analogy can fail if you look in the wrong places. If $\mathbb Z= \mathbb F_1[t]$, what is $\mathbb F_1[t^2]$? Also consider the zeta functions of these fields. The Riemann zeta function has infinitely many zeroes, while the zeta function of $\mathbb F_q(t)$ has none. To study the zeros of the Riemann zeta function in the function field model, mathematicians pass to the limit of infinitely large $g$. James Borger also pointed out the issues with the discriminant.

So clearly in translating questions between the function field and number field worlds some discretion is necessary.

Similar to this all currently existing $\mathbb F_1$-theories have some kind of problem where they don't fit with our intuitive idea of what an $\mathbb F_1$-theory should look like - in fact I believe that is known to be contradictory. Certainly good mathematical work can be done by finding clever workarounds and deftly avoiding these problems, and it might go so far as to solve completely or make progress on otherwise intractable number field problems.

Third let me say that, not knowing much about string theory, it seems to me that your other question should not run into these problems. Indeed you seem to be concerned only with (various sophisticated forms of) analysis and integration over these fields. Identities of integrals and things like that tend to translate very well among different contexts once you've found the right way of looking at them - I have seen many examples of this. But I don't have any idea what to do in your particular problem.